# how to display current webview in android

Tags: android, webview, viewflipper

I have 3 webviews displaying query result for a search string from 3 search engines.. if google is displayed, i have yahoo and ask buttons at the bottom....when I click either of them, I get results for the entered query...

```
                    if(btn2.getText()=="Yahoo")
        {
            wv2.loadUrl("http://search.yahoo.com/bin/search?p="+value);
            vf.setDisplayedChild(1);
            System.out.println("Yahoo is working");
            btn1.setText("Ask");
            btn2.setText("Google");
        }

        else if(btn2.getText()=="Ask")
        {
            wv3.loadUrl("http://www.ask.com/web?q="+value);
            vf.setDisplayedChild(2);
            System.out.println("Ask is working");
            btn1.setText("Google");
            btn2.setText("Yahoo");
        }
        else if(btn2.getText()=="Google")
        {   
            wv1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/search?q="+value);
            vf.setDisplayedChild(0);
            System.out.println("Google is working");
            btn1.setText("Yahoo");
            btn2.setText("Ask");
        }
```

With the above code, each time i press the buttons at the bottom, I am getting query results regenerated,,,,I want to display the result if i select any....
For ex: Google results displayed the search string "FACEBOOK" and i selected first result in that....Suppose I select Yahoo button at the bottom, then yahoo is displayed and I have a google button formed at the bottom....when I click that google button, I want the first result that I selected previously...Kindly suggest what changes to make in the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method:

webview.getURL() on each button click.and get url that in string and just load that in that url in webview.

I would just mention here take relevant webview for that method means as for Yahoo may you take webview1 like this.

Answer (score 0):

Why using three webviews? Can't you do all that stuff in one webview? And if you are using three different webviews then what is the need of loading url again and again simply make rest of the two webviews invisible when showing any 1 result (just make present one visible).

Comment: @NJOY; Yes I have made the other 2 webviews invisible and displaying only one webview. But I need to flip through all and show al 3 search engine results...which is why I have used 3 webviews

Comment: ya but u doin mistake here now when u press those button again just make the webview corresponding 2 it visible dont load url again. got my point you will again get your selected result on webview back....

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Web View tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) and [WebView class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do 1 thing: make 3 string variables:

```
latestGoogleURL...,  
latestAskURL...,  
latestYahooURL...,
```

Now whenever you click some result update these URL in corresponding search result. For example, if you click first Facebook result from Google than save the URL of first Facebook result in latestGoogleURL, then when you load them load these URL on button click as follows:

```
 wv1.loadUrl(latestGoogleResult);
```